# how to Converting below json and load into json.loads()?

Tags: json, python-2.7

While loading below json into `json.loads()`, I get error on `"value"` as it does not contain `""`.

```
jstring = '{"ABC": {value: "2787456", basevalue: "34453176"}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Keys need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
>>> jstring='{"ABC":{"value":"2787456","basevalue":"34453176"}}'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(jstring)
{u'ABC': {u'value': u'2787456', u'basevalue': u'34453176'}}
```

Comment: Yes.. but my jstring was huge, is there any function to convert the value in double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `value` must also be enclosed in quote marks like this `"value"`, in order to be parsed as json key.

```
jstring = '{"ABC": {"value": "2787456", "base value": "34453176"}}'
```